# ESP8266-12 SPI Interfacing

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, esp8266, microchip, esp32

I want to make an Interfacing between my pic microcontroller and the ESP8266-12 through SPI protocol, but i found two types of SPI in the ESP8266-12, the Hspi and on gpio 12,13,14 and another one on 6,7,11 , so which one should I use and what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Use GPIO6,GPIO7 and GPIO11. The other one is used for the processor to access the serial flash memory.